# React.js best practice regarding listening to window events from components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am animating several React.js components based on their position in the viewport. If the component is in the viewport, animate the opacity to 1, if it's not in the viewport, animate its opacity to 0. I am using `getBoundingClient()`'s `top` and `bottom` properties to determine if the component is within the viewport.

ComponentA shows the pattern I followed for the other B, C, and D components. They each are listening for the `window` scroll event.

Is this the "React" way to do this by each component having its having to add an event listener to the `window`? Multiple scroll event listeners on the same window?

Or is there a better way by adding the scroll event listener to the window once at the `Home` owner component? Then would the ownee child components still be able to know where they are in the DOM using the `getBoundingClient()`?

```
Home = React.createClass({
 render: function() {
    <div>
       <ComponentA />
       <ComponentB />
       <ComponentC />
       <ComponentD />
    </div>
  };
});

ComponentA = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
   window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
},
  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
   },

handleScroll: function() {
  var domElement = this.refs.domElement.getDOMNode();
  this.inViewPort(domElement);
},

inViewPort: function(element) {
  var elementBounds = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  (elementBounds.top <= 769 && elementBounds.bottom >= 430) ? TweenMax.to(element, 1.5, { opacity: 1 }) : TweenMax.to(element, 1.5, { opacity: 0 });
},
render: function() {
  return (/* html to render */);
 }

});
```

Comment: Can a high level component like react-router or redux's connect feasible?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There are a few different ways you could do this. One is through composition:

```
var React = require("react");
var _ = require("underscore");

var ScrollWrapper = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        onWindowScroll: React.PropTypes.func
    },

    handleScroll: function(event) {
        // Do something generic, if you have to
        console.log("ScrollWrapper's handleScroll");

        // Call the passed-in prop
        if (this.props.onWindowScroll) this.props.onWindowScroll(event);
    },

    render: function () {
        return this.props.children;
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        if (this.props.onWindowScroll) window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
    },

    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        if (this.props.onWindowScroll) window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
    }
});

var ComponentA = React.createClass({
    handleScroll: function(event) {
        console.log("ComponentA's handleScroll");
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <ScrollWrapper onWindowScroll={this.handleScroll}>
                <div>whatever</div>
            </ScrollWrapper>
        );
    }
});
```

Now, you can place your generic logic in the `ScrollWrapper` component, and suddenly it becomes reusable. You could create a `ComponentB` that renders a `ScrollWrapper` just like `ComponentA` does.

To satisfy your example, maybe you'll have to pass the `ScrollWrapper` some extra props from `ComponentA`. Maybe you'll pass it a prop that contains an instance of the `ref` to call your logic on. You could even pass it some options or arguments to customize the tween or the bounds. I didn't code any of this because I think you'll understand it and be able to customize/write it for yourself with the base I've provided.

The other way to achieve this sort of thing is through a Mixin. Although, there's a lot of talk about if Mixins are good or bad, and they might even be being deprecated by React in the future? You can do some reading about this and decide for yourself what you think.

Comment: for unidirectional flow, separation of side effects/concerns, reduced redundancy, more reuse

Answer (score 71):

Here it is in functional style with the useEffect hook:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const onScroll = (event) => console.info("scrolling", event);
      
    window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
    
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: Is it necessary to remove events from window as well?
I understand it is for most elements like `div`s and others as they can unmount but does it matter when window unmounts?

Comment: It matters for two reasons: First you probably do not want the event listener to continue receiving events after the component in which the `useEffect` call happens gets unmounted, so removing the event listener stops that from happening. Secondly, to save on memory. Even if you don't care about the event handler running, the handler does stay in memory as long as it's registered, and any time you render a new instance of the component that uses the `useEffect` call, it registers a new handler, increasing memory usage.

Answer (score 22):

Here is a simpler code snippet that should work as required. You are missing the `this` binding, as such, when you execute `window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);` you are actually pointing `this` to the window object.

Instead you will need to bind this in the constructor. Hope it

```
class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }
  handleScroll(e) {
    console.log('scroll event');
    console.log(e);
  }

  render() {
    return (
     <div>
       <ComponentA />
       <ComponentB />
       <ComponentC />
       <ComponentD />
     </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Another option is the below, both options should work :)

```
class Home extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll.bind(this));
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll.bind(this));
  }
  handleScroll(e) {
    console.log('scroll event');
    console.log(e);
  }

  render() {
    return (
     <div>
       <ComponentA />
       <ComponentB />
       <ComponentC />
       <ComponentD />
     </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it mean that we get 4 eventHandlers for scroll event for ComponentsA, B and so on?

Comment: No @AksanaTolstoguzova there's only 1 event handler for the scroll event

Comment: Don't do this. When you bind in the lifecycle methods you're creating a new instance of the given instance method, so removing the event listeners won't work. Bind the instance methods in the constructor, not the lifecycle methods. Also, defer to the composition approach in the accepted answer.

Comment: This does not work for me today.  Has it changed ?

Answer (score 2):

I'd definitely add one event listener / component. The ideology is to have separated components that can be reused and placed "anywhere" in the application - to minimize code redundancy.

Your approach to keep an event listner per compnenent is therefore valid.