# React Native: can't find variable document

Tags: react-native

I am trying to add EventListner to document object but getting error as `cant find variable document` .
Below is my code

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Easing, Text, View, StyleSheet , Button , TextInput , TouchableOpacity , TouchableWithoutFeedback, Animated} from 'react-native';
import DateTimePicker from "react-native-modal-datetime-picker";
import { Platform, StatusBar} from 'react-native';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
// You can import from local files

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm

export default class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    menuwidth: new  Animated.Value(0)
  }

  showmenu = () => {
    Animated.timing(this.state.menuwidth,{
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 550,
      easing: Easing.linear
    }).start();
  }

  hidemenu = () => {

  }


  componentWillMount() {
    document.addEventListner('click',this.clickoutside,false)
  }

  componentWillUnMount(){
    document.removeEventListner('click',this.clickoutside,false)
  }

  render() {

    const menuwidth_interpole = this.state.menuwidth.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0,1],
      outputRange: ['-50%','0%']
    })
```

am i missing something ? . i am using this tutorial https://medium.com/@pitipatdop/little-neat-trick-to-capture-click-outside-with-react-hook-ba77c37c7e82 to resolve click outside component issue.

Comment: 1) You spelled "Listener" wrong. It should be addEventListener and removeEventListener.   2) I think you need to use window.addEventListener instead of document. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32896624/react-js-best-practice-regarding-listening-to-window-events-from-components

Comment: Is document valid in React Native?

Comment: You cannot use `document` in React Native, you can create a backdrop behind the menu then on press backdrop you can hide it.