# TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null react.js application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been struggling with this bug. I keep getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null on my react application. I'm quite new to react so have been trying t figure out the issue with no avail. Here's the error and my component, anyone know what the problem is?

**The TypeError Message as text:**

```
←→1 of 8 errors on the page
TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
(anonymous function)
http://localhost:3003/static/js/main.chunk.js:8044:49
  8041 | var value = window.scrollY;
  8042 | 
  8043 | if (value > 100) {
> 8044 |   document.querySelector('.header--fixed').classList.add('sticky');
       |                                           ^  8045 | } else {
  8046 |   document.querySelector('.header--fixed').classList.remove('sticky');
  8047 | }
View source
This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.
```

**My Component/ code:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {FaTwitter ,FaInstagram ,FaFacebookF , FaLinkedinIn } from "react-icons/fa";
import { FiX , FiMenu} from "react-icons/fi";
import Scrollspy from 'react-scrollspy'
import mypdf from "../../../public/assets/files/Sarah-Chosen-CV.pdf";

const SocialShare = [
    // {Social: <FaFacebookF /> , link: 'https://www.facebook.com/'},
    // {Social: <FaInstagram /> , link: 'https://www.instagram.com/'},
    // {Social: <FaTwitter /> , link: 'https://twitter.com/'},
    {Social: <FaLinkedinIn /> , link: 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/sarah-chosen/'},
]
class HeaderThree extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.menuTrigger = this.menuTrigger.bind(this);
        this.CLoseMenuTrigger = this.CLoseMenuTrigger.bind(this);
        this.stickyHeader = this.stickyHeader.bind(this);

       //  this.subMetuTrigger = this.subMetuTrigger.bind(this);
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            console.log('All assets are loaded');
        })
        
    }
    menuTrigger() {
        document.querySelector('.header-wrapper').classList.toggle('menu-open')
    }
    
    CLoseMenuTrigger() {
        document.querySelector('.header-wrapper').classList.remove('menu-open')
    }

    stickyHeader () {}

    render(){

        window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
            var value = window.scrollY;
            if (value > 100) {
                document.querySelector('.header--fixed').classList.add('sticky')
            }else{
                document.querySelector('.header--fixed').classList.remove('sticky')
            }
        });

        var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.has-droupdown > a');
        for(var i in elements) {
            if(elements.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                elements[i].onclick = function() {
                    this.parentElement.querySelector('.submenu').classList.toggle("active");
                    this.classList.toggle("open");
                }
            }
        }
        const { logo, color='default-color' } = this.props;
        let logoUrl;
        if(logo === 'light'){
            logoUrl = <img src="/assets/images/logo/logo-light.png" alt="Digital Agency" />;
        }else if(logo === 'dark'){
            logoUrl = <img src="/assets/images/logo/logo-dark.png" alt="Digital Agency" />;
        }else if(logo === 'symbol-dark'){
            logoUrl = <img src="/assets/images/logo/logo-symbol-dark.png" alt="Digital Agency" />;
        }else if(logo === 'symbol-light'){
            logoUrl = <img src="/assets/images/logo/logo-symbol-light.png" alt="Digital Agency" />;
        }else{
            logoUrl = <img src="/assets/images/logo/logo.png" alt="Digital Agency" />;
        }
        
        return (
          <header
            className={`header-area header-style-two header--fixed ${color}`}
          >
            <div className="header-wrapper">
              <div className="header-left d-flex align-items-center">
                <div className="logo">
                  <a href={this.props.homeLink}>{logoUrl}</a>
                </div>
                <nav className="mainmenunav d-lg-block ml--50">
                  <Scrollspy
                    className="mainmenu"
                    items={[
                      "home",
                      "about",
                      "service",
                      "portfolio",
                      "blog",
                      "contact",
                    ]}
                    currentClassName="is-current"
                    offset={-200}
                  >
                    <li>
                      <a href="#home">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#service">Skillset</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                  </Scrollspy>
                </nav>
              </div>
              <div className="header-right">
                <div className="social-share-inner">
                  <ul className="social-share social-style--2 color-black d-flex justify-content-start liststyle">
                    {SocialShare.map((val, i) => (
                      <li key={i}>
                        <a href={`${val.link}`}>{val.Social}</a>
                      </li>
                    ))}
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div className="header-btn">
                  <a className="rn-btn" href={mypdf} download="Sarah-Chosen-CV.pdf">
                    <span>download CV</span>
                  </a>
                </div>
                {/* Start Humberger Menu  */}
                <div className="humberger-menu d-block d-lg-none pl--20">
                  <span
                    onClick={this.menuTrigger}
                    className="menutrigger text-white"
                  >
                    <FiMenu />
                  </span>
                </div>
                {/* End Humberger Menu  */}
                <div className="close-menu d-block d-lg-none">
                  <span
                    onClick={this.CLoseMenuTrigger}
                    className="closeTrigger"
                  >
                    <FiX />
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </header>
        );
    }
}


export default HeaderThree;
```

Comment: The code looks like not React-way. Try not to use `querySelector`.
Also you should know `render` can be invoked multiple times. Therefore your scroll subscription will be multiplied. Also, you don't have `removeEventListener`, so it can be reason for memory leak and bugs.
I advise you read something like best practice in React and documentation first to understand core concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Adding event listeners in react components should happen when the component has its DOM representation is ready. `componentDidMount` is called after the component is mounted and has a DOM representation. This is often a place where you would attach generic DOM events.

So try to move the code where you assign the listener for `scroll` event to `componentDidMount` lifecycle method. and also **remove the event** listener in `componentWillUnmount`. What makes this more important is that React components will often be re-rendered, and the code to set up event listeners will have the opportunity to run many times. This can create errors by setting up multiple listeners where we're actually expecting a single listener run per event occurrence.

Additionally, React-based UIs are often used in single-page apps that exist within long-lived browser sessions. This creates an environment where memory leaks can become serious more often.

Check out this article from react: https://react-cn.github.io/react/tips/dom-event-listeners.html

and also this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32896624/react-js-best-practice-regarding-listening-to-window-events-from-components) describe how to wrap a component with scrollWrapper that handles the scroll event